# Assigning variable to a variable inside if statement

Tags: linux, bash, variables, if-statement

I am trying to assign a variable from a prompt input choice with no luck. If the user inputs 1, I want target_db_name = "database2".
My code:

```
while true; do
    read -p  "What is the table name?" table_name
table_name=${table_name,,}
    if hdfs dfs -test -e /foo/$table_name ; 
    then read -p "What is the target database you want to copy the 
“foo.${table_name}” table to?

Your three options are:
1) database1
2) database2
3) database3

Type 1, 2, or 3: " target_db;

(((Here is where I want to state if $target_db = "1" then target_db_name 
= "database1", if $target_db = "2" then target_db_name = "database2" etc...)))

read -p "Would you like to begin the HDFS copy with the following configuration:

Target Database: ${target_db_name}  
Table Name: ${table_name}

Continue (Y/N):"

else echo "Please provide a valid table name.
Exiting this script" ; exit ; fi

done
```

I have tried creating another if statement with no luck.

```
"....Type 1, 2, or 3: " target_db;
else if $target_db = "1" then target_db_name = "edw_qa_history"; fi
```

Comment: Please show what you tried, so we can explain what you did wrong.

Comment: Remember that variable assignments in `bash` don't have a space around the `=`.

Comment: And you should probably use `case` rather than `if`.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here. Beyond that, please try to build a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run to see the problem themselves. (If it requires `hdfs`, then it fails the "someone else can run" requirement; and if the problem isn't explicitly about, say, prompting the user, then prompts shouldn't be included -- if you need a variable to have a value, just hardcode it directly).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you so much for the advise/education. Bookmarked shellcheck.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if $target_db = "1" then` won't work, because what follows `if` must be a command, not a test expression. Now, the most common command used in `if` statements is `[` (yes, that's actually a command name; it's synonymous with the `test` command), which takes a test expression (and a close bracket) as its arguments and succeeds or fails depending on whether the expression is true or not. So the correct syntax would be something like:

```
if [ "$target_db" = "1" ]; then
```

Note that there are two other differences from what you had: I put double-quotes around the variable reference (almost always a good idea, to avoid may parsing oddities), and added a semicolon before `then` (needed to indicate where the arguments to `[` end and shell syntax resumes). I also notice you have semicolons at the end of many lines of your script; this isn't necessary, the end-of-line is enough to indicate the end of a command. It's only if you have another command (or something like `then`) on the same line that you need a semicolon as a delimiter.

HOWEVER, as @Barmar pointed out in a comment, `case` would probably be better than a list of `if` and `elif` statements here. `case` is intended specifically for comparing a string against a list of other strings (or patterns), and executing different things depending on which one it matches. It looks something like this:

```
case "$target_db" in
    1) target_db_name="database1" ;;
    2) target_db_name="database2" ;;
    3) target_db_name="database3" ;;
    *) "Please provide a valid table name. Exiting this script" ; exit ;;
esac
```

Here, the double-semicolon *is* needed, even at the end of a line, to indicate the end of each case. Also, note that the `*` pattern (the last case) matches anything, so it functions like an `else` would in an `if` ... `elif` ... sequence.

Final note: use [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to sanity-check your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if` statement to map the number to an array; you just need an array.

```
db_names=(
   "datebase 1"
   "database 2"
   "database 3"
)

# ...

target_db_name=${db_names[$target_db - 1]}
if [[ -z $target_db_name ]]; then
    exit
fi
```